# Problems with a spinner on relativelayout xml

Tags: android, spinner, android-relativelayout

i am doing an xml layout file, and i want to have my spinner in the right of a textview, but i am having problems... when i test the layout, my spinner is not in the correct possition, it's a little more down and it haves very small lenght, is not 180px as i said in the layout.

there is the xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/PermissionLabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/perlabel"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
    android:layout_below="@id/salto3"/>
<Spinner 
    android:id="@+id/Permission"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:prompt="@string/perlabel"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/PermissionLabel"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:width="180px"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dip"/>
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/salto4"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/saltodelinea2"
    android:layout_below="@id/PermissionLabel"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/HoursRangeLabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hoursrangelabel"
    android:layout_below="@id/salto4"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/From"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/HoursRangeLabel"
    android:width="70px"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/Email"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dip"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ToLabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/tolabel"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/From"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/From"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-10px"/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/To"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/From"
    android:width="70px"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it really necessary that all items in your layout are "Relative" to each other?  It sure doesn't appear that way from the properties you set on each item.

I would recommend trying something like a LinearLayout, and then if it is critical a certain item is Relative to another item, use a RelativeLayout inside the LinearLayout for those particular items.